# GAE Python Gcloud - Command to run in production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy my python app to production using gcloud, but this weird message pops up everytime and  I didn't find any information abou this googling...

When I run:

```
gcloud preview app deploy
```

This message apepars:

```
This looks like a Python app.  If so, please enter the command to run 
to run the app in production (enter nothing if it's not a python app):
```

I've tried to execute the regular command using appcfg.py:

```
❯ appcfg.py -A <appname> update app.yaml
```

But it throws a timeout everytime.

Anyone knows what am I supposed to do in this situation?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My App.yaml

```
runtime: python
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
vm: true

handlers:

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin

  #libraries:
  #- name: MySQLdb
  #version: "latest"

builtins:
- remote_api: on
- deferred: on

resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

**EDIT 2**

I've changed my runtime to custom and now it does  not asks nothing anymore. The problem now is that it throws a timeout:

```
(gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying)
```

I found information about this error, I'll get back here if I figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an `app.yaml` file in your directory? If so, what are its contents?

Comment: Hello @ZacharyNewman yes, I do I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Dyego: What did you do after the prompt regarding "Python app" ? Just hitting the return key at this prompt should create the dockerfile and upload your app.

Comment: For one, your `- url: .*` wildcard handler should come last.  The `- url: /_ah/queue/deferred` handler will never get hit.  But that is not the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this question doesn't have an accepted answer, I'll post one here for any future readers.

The deployment was prompting for an entrypoint, as it was not specified in the app.yaml. This field is required to run a Python runtime app on the flexible environment. Changing the runtime to 'custom' won't prompt for it, but the app container still doesn't know how to run your app, so the VM will fail to start.

More details are available in the documentation:

**Application startup**
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I "cd"ed into the directory where the app.yaml was and ran the command again and it deployed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that I needed to add the "entrypoint" property within my app.yaml and configure it to point at my startup script.  I'm running a Python 3.5 app (Flask) with the following app.yaml. Note the entrypoint property:

```
runtime: python
threadsafe: true
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT application:APP

runtime_config:
     python_version: 3.5

handlers: 
- url: /.*
  script: application.APP
```